# Как отправить запрос с сервера (PHP) в приложение на компе клиента (C#)

Tags: php, c#

В общем, суть такая:
Мне нужно посылать запрос из PHP скрипта на сервере в приложение, которое будет установлено на компе.

Делаю я это потому что мне из веб-сервиса нужно отсылать запрос на оборудование, которое будет подключено к компу, и имеет свои дрова.

Я придумал одно решение, и пока не понял насколько оно костыльное, но все же: при запуске приложения оно запускает локальный сервер (`127.0.0.1:8005`), и принимает в себя данные по сокету. При обращении к этому локальному серверу из адресной строки браузера коннекшн есть: приложение возвращает мне ответ. Но я не предусмотрел того, что запросы на `127.0.0.1:8005` с сервера будут обращаться не к локальному серверу компа, а к самому себе.

Был также вариант с использованием:

```php
header('Location: http://127.0.0.1:8005');
```

... но это показалось мне костыльным.

Примерно такая ситуация. Если это костыльный треш - пишите. Если есть предположения как это можно реализовать - пишите.

Comment: Это даже не костыльный треш. Это просто треш, который в принципе не работает. Если бы сайты могли по желанию своей левой пятки ходить на компы пользователей, то интернета бы в нынешнем виде просто бы не существовало. Соединение может инициировать только клиент. А дальше есть два варианта - либо с какой-то частотой опрашивать, либо устанавливать постоянное соединение, ключевое слово - вебсокет

Comment: Единственное исключение - это если у вас не персональный компьютер дома на теплом пледике по вифи, а сервер, изначально предназначенный для обслуживания запросов из сети. В этом случае на него зайти можно. Но я так понимаю что это не ваш случай.

Comment: Пора начинать отличать фронтенд от бэкенда. Тогда и встанет все на свои места. Предложенное вами решение будет работать только на вашем компе, и больше нигде. Либо я вообще не понял, что происходит.

Comment: Я присоединяюсь к совету использовать WebSocket. Приложение на C# соединяется через такой сокет с сервером на PHP. После чего сервер может по собственному желанию слать любые запросы на клиента.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov для подкрепления полученной мной информации: в роли сокета-сервера(далее СС) у нас выступает удаленный сервер, а в роли сокета-клиента(далее СК) - C# приложение, так? И получается, что СС отсылает запрос, который прослушивает СК, и я могу получить данные, которые я отправил с СС, уже в приложении?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Спасибо)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Только не совсем понятно, как поставить слушателя на удаленный сервер. Я нашел миллион примеров, и не могу в них разобраться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я могу взять примеры подключения сокета к удаленному серверу :с

Comment: Вероятно следует задать два новых вопроса: первый про написание сервера на PHP с использованием WebSocket, второй - про написание клиента на C# с использованием WebSocket. / Кстати: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1332567/184217

Answer (score 0):

Не столь трешовое, но теоретически рабочее решение:

Вам нужна архитектура с сервером, отвечающим за команды и состояния оборудования, у вашего PHP должна быть вёбморда, чтобы тыкать на кнопки управления оборудованием, с состоянием (выполнено или нет), а так-же отменой команд (таймауты), у PHP должен быть некий "контроллер состояний" в ОЗУ или БД, который будет запрашивать приложение на C# для управления оборудованием, а так-же нужна сама программа на C#, которая обращается к PHP, извлекает список команд, и выполняет их у себя, управляя оборудованием, и возвращая ответ к PHP о статусе: успешно или не успешно.

Во-первых: PHP тут не очень подходит (ИМХО), но кажется в нём есть статические поля, которые помогут в реализации данной идеи.
Во-вторых: это всё-равно довольно сложно, т.к. нужно продумывать много моментов, с синхронизацией, недоступностью устройств, формате сообщений/команд.
В-третьих: самое сложное это "контроллер состояний", если сможете реализовать его у себя на PHP - всё остальное будет лучше. Но ту уже вам не помогут, т.к. данных вы не предоставили, что за устройства, какие команды, если же просто строка (а C# сам разберётся), то вам нужно контролировать какому устройству от кого, когда, и какая команда. Так-же приложение C# должно само сообщать о статусе устройств на PHP, периодично по таймеру.

Сделайте для начала:

1. Вёбморду с 1 индикатором и 2мя кнопками (вкл/выкл)
2. PHP, который хранит состояние устройства для индикатора и держит список команд, ожидая запросы от морды и приложения (функции: выдать вёбморду с индикатором и списком команд в очереди, принять нажатие из морды и добавить команду от морды в список команд, выдать список команд приложению C# по запросу, очистить список команд)
3. C# приложение (форма с индикатором) которое не управляет никаким устройством и просто так-же хранит у себя это состояние и периодически запрашивает команды, и на основе команды меняет состояние индикатора на форме

Это просто минимальное возможное решение, хотите проще? Тогда исключайте PHP, но сильно проще не станет.

Comment: Рассказываю детальнее: 
Оборудование - ПОС терминал. Делаю веб-сервис касс (или что-то в этом роде), где при нажатии одной волшебной кнопочки на пос терминал должна придти команда оплаты со стоимостью.
От пыхи отказаться вряд ли смогу, так как проект уже большой, и весь написан на ней (индусами, кстати. Я плачу)
Вы пишите : _добавить команду от морды в список команд, выдать список команд приложению C# по запросу_...
А вот вопрос как это сделать? Как передать команды с пыхи на шарп?

Comment: @Andrey компьютер ведь в локальной сети и у него есть айпи адрес? Тогда вообще непонятно, в чем вопрос, поскольку ответов на "как отправить http запрос на пхп" примерно миллион

Comment: @Andrey при нажатии на кнопку браузер формирует запрос к серверу с PHP, например банальный button-submit запрос, дальше этот запрос пыха обрабатывает и помещает его в список запросов, например array_push, сам список запросов должен держаться в ОЗУ, т.е. массив должен быть статическим, само C# приложение по таймеру читает страницу, например: /array.php?from=pos_terminal, где php берёт массив, упаковывает его в json и возвращает как страницу, C# его уже разбирает и выполняет команды.

Comment: @Blackmeser тогда у меня есть еще один вопросик. Отправку запроса на терминал, желательно, сделать быстрой, чтобы покупатель не стоял пять минут ожидая команды терминала. И вопрос, собственно в том, что нормально ли делать таймер, который каждые 5 секунд отправляет запрос к странице /array.php? Не нагружено ли будет для сервера?
Я думал в сторону сокетов, чтобы выдавать инфу только по запросу. Но пока не сильно разобрался

Comment: Мне кажется, автор не спрашивал как отправить данные с фронта в пхп, и как их потом в пхп хранить. Но возможно у вас с ним телепатическая связь :)

Comment: Хотя если бы он (вместо комментариев про душность) родил наконец, есть ли доступ с сервера к кассе, то тогда бы и вообще не понадобились эти танцы вприсядку со списком запросов в ОЗУ, опросами по таймеру и прочем лебединым озером

Comment: ржу :D
доступ с сервера к кассе есть, реализован на АПИ

Comment: @Andrey В идеале можно 100мс, зависит от того, сколько pos-терминалов скрипт должен обслуживать и как далеко он, главное ещё чтобы очистка массива была. Можете сокеты, можете вёбсокеты, можете как угодно. Главное чтобы было надёжно, а не быстро.

Comment: @Ипатьев ну речь шла про C# приложение и некое устройство, если через API можно произвести оплату, то C# по идее вообще можно выкинуть.

Comment: @Blackmeser 
Касса и пос терминал - это немного разные вещи, все же)
По апи я могу только отсылать только информацию о чеках (для ФНС итд)
А к пос терминалу можно подключиться только через приложение на компе, в котором я буду подключать либы для работы с терминалом