# Как подключиться к Laravel WebSocket с клиента Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, laravel, websocket, xamarin, xamarin.forms

у меня есть сервер На Laravel в котором я реализовал библиотеку Laravel WebSocet. Запускаю команду `laravel websocket: serve`, стартует все нормально, самое важное что у меня не получается это подключится с клиента в XamarinForms я использую для этого библиотеку `SocketIOClient`

Вот мой код

```
public async Task connectAsync()
{
    Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
    var uri = new Uri("ws://192.168.0.105:6001");

    var socket = new SocketIO(uri, new SocketIOOptions
    {
        Query = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
             {"APP_NAME", "messager" },
             {"PUSHER_APP_KEY", "ABCDEFG" },
             {"PUSHER_APP_ID", "1234" },
             {"PUSHER_APP_SECRET", "HIJKLMNOP" },
             {"enabledTransports", "ws" },
             {"PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER", "mt1" },
             { "wsPort","6001"},
             {"wsHost","ws://192.168.0.105:6001" }
         }
    });

    socket.OnConnected += Socket_OnConnected;
    socket.OnPing += Socket_OnPing;
    socket.OnPong += Socket_OnPong;
    socket.OnDisconnected += Socket_OnDisconnected;
    socket.OnReconnectAttempt += Socket_OnReconnecting;

    try
    {
        await socket.ConnectAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }

    socket.On("event-name", response =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"server: {response}");
    });

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static async void Socket_OnConnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Socket_OnConnected");
    var socket = sender as SocketIO;

    await socket.EmitAsync("subscribe", new
    {
        channel = "channelName",
        auth = ""
    });
}

private static void Socket_OnPing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ping");
}

private static void Socket_OnPong(object sender, TimeSpan e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Pong: " + e.TotalMilliseconds);
}

private static void Socket_OnDisconnected(object sender, string e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("disconnect: " + e);
}

private static void Socket_OnReconnecting(object sender, int e)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Reconnecting: attempt = {e}");
}
```

Comment: А Вы уверены, что к сокету по `http` надо подключаться? Используйте протоколы `ws` или `wss`

Comment: Пробывал подумал не работает из за этого

Comment: Однако и через ws и через http не получается

Comment: Как вы поняли, что не получается? Ошибка какая-то? Почему вы уверены, что сервер работает исправно, как проверили этот факт?

Comment: Логи идут на сервере , есть библиотека Pusher JS , которая создает страницу в браузере с таблицей подключений и кнопкой подключиться , но с клиента xamarin отправить запрос на этот адрес не удается

Comment: Вобщем сервер исправный это точно

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Оказалось что библиотека устарела, я воспользовался библиотекой `System.Net.WebSockets.Client`.
И указал другую ссылку, оказалось что `LaravelWebSocket` в связке С `Pusher` формировал ключ который надо было указать в ссылке,`/app/ABCDEFG` Эту часть пути надо было дописать в итоге получалась целая ссылка
`ws://192.168.0.105:6001/app/ABCDEFG`
Где ABCDEFG ключ который вы создали при помощи Pusher

Вот здесь можно посмотреть как ставить LaravelWebSocket
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIGy7-7gGXI&ab_channel=DevMarketer

Вот Код

```
ClientWebSocket client = new ClientWebSocket();

public ChatViewModel()
{
    ConnectToServerAsync();
}

async void ConnectToServerAsync()
{
    await client.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://192.168.0.105:6001/app/ABCDEFG"), CancellationToken.None);
    var data = "Helo";
    var encoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    var buffer = new ArraySegment<Byte>(encoder, 0, encoder.Length);
    await client.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
    //client.Abort();
}
```

Comment: Вот это я понимаю! Вот это - классно,когда автор сам разобрался и сам ответил на вопрос, причем так, что это и другим в похожей ситуации будет полезно!

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы в своих вопросах и ответах форматировали код с нормальными отступами,а не как вставилось, так и запостил.

Comment: Я считаю что все читабельно , основные элементы вопроса были выделены , сам код то же отдельно отредактирован  и прекрасно виден

Comment: @ДанилСтрученков это потому что я его отредактировал. :)